# BeautifulSoup doesn't return the expected tag as Chrome

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a page to learn beautifulSoup, here is the code

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 'https://www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Delirium/w0brcb'
resp = req.get(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('results')
print(len(res))
```

**Result: 0**

The goal is to get the first price.

I tried to look for the tag in Chrome and it's there, but probably the browser does another requests to get the results.

Can someone explain what am I missing here?
[website's source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwc60.png)

Comment: The web site probably uses AJAX to add the tag. Use `View Source` to see what BS processes. If you need to get dynamic data, you should either use an API or use Selenium WebDriver to run the JavaScript.

Comment: You just need to use 'resp.text', after that you can reach to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

### Problems with the code

Your code is looking for a "results"-element. What you really have to look for (based on your screenshot) is a div-element with the class "results".

So try this:

```
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"results"})
```

But if you want the price you have to dig deeper for the element which contains the price:

```
price = soup.find("span", attrs={"data-field":"price"}).text
```

### Problems with the site

It seems the site is loading data by Ajax. With *Requests* you get the page before/without Ajax data call.

In this case you should change from *Requests* to *Selenium* module. This will navigate through a "real Browser" and you can wait until data is finally loaded before you start scraping.

[Documentation: Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)